# How to increment variable value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to increment the `id` value and a `td` element.

When I tried to increment a value by creating a simple button it doesn't work but, when I implemented the solution to my code it never works. Not sure if the nested `onclick` is affecting the flow

```
          $(document).ready(function(){ 
          $('#coursenumber').change(function() {
                
            //alert($(this).val());
            var credit = $(this).val().split('|');
            var data = {};
            data.action = 'getcredits';
            data.strm = credit[0];
            data.sessioncode = credit[1];
            data.subject = credit[2];
            data.coursenumber = credit[3];
            
            $("#strm").attr('value', data.strm);
            $("#session_code").attr('value', data.sessioncode);
            $("#subjectss").attr('value', data.subject);
            $("#course_numbers").attr('value', data.coursenumber);


            
            //add values to hidden input tags
            
            
            //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            

                $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '../excesscreditautomation/ajaxxx.do',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: $.param(data),
                    success: function (response){
                        
                        //$('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(response);
                        //displayCourses(response);,
                       console.log(response); 
                      displayCredits(response);
                      
                      //add button function
                      //onclick function pass the values to html
                      $(document).on('click','#add-course', function (){
                         
    
                       $("#coursenumberTab").hide();
                       $("#subjectTab").hide();
                       $("#mycreditsTab").hide();
                       
                       $("#strm").empty();
                       $("#session_code").empty();
                       $("#subject").empty();
                       $("#coursenumber").empty();
                       $("#mycredits").empty();
                       
                       
                          
                          
                          var myOption = 1; 
                            

                            
                          
                          for (var i = 0; i < response.course.length; i++) {
                              console.log(response.course.length);
                              $('#table-2 > tbody:last-child')
                                      .append('<tr id="optionid' + ++myOption + '">' + 
                                        '<td>'+ ++myOption + '</td> ' + 
                                        '<td>' + response.course[i].strm + '</td> ' + 
                                        '<td>' + response.course[i].subject + '</td> ' + 
                                        '<td>' + response.course[i].coursenumber + '</td>  ' + 
                                        '<td>' + response.course[i].credits + '</td> ' + 
                                        '<td><a href="#">Delete</a></td> ' + 
                                    '</tr>' );
                            
                           
                          }
                          
                         

                          
                      });
                                                      

                            
                        
                        
                    },error: function(){
                            alert('failure');
                        }
                });
                
                
            });//end #credit

          });
```

So, `myOption` never change/increment the value.

Another problem is that when I try to `add-course` for the second time it's adding the `td` twice. In other words, it's duplicating the course. The first time you run the query it does add the `td` once.

UPDATE: Note that the loop is returning only 1 result each time I press the add course button. So, I need the number `myOption` to stay there. For example, if I press the add-course button the first myOption should be 1..then I want to add a new course and so I press the add-course button again, and now the id should say myOption2 and so on..is like creating a LIKE button and the number increase every time you press that button.

Right now the append `tr` is just adding the same id number each time I press `add-course`

Comment: When you use `myOption++` you  are incrementing 1 after its value is used. If you want to do it beforehand, you can do `++myOption`. However you do not need to do it in so many places. Just start it at 1, and then increment it by 1 at the start of your for loop (or just use `i` since you're already using that and incrementing it.)

Comment: You need to assign those IDs for some reason?  I can't think of a good one.

Comment: @James Yes, Each course added should have a different id because the table is draggable; people will be able to drag the row and change the order...so, for that reason, I need every new `tr` to have its own id.

Comment: @tmdesigned Note tha t the loop is returning only 1 result each time I press the `add course` button. So, I need the number to stay there. For example, if I press the `add-course` button the first `myOption` should be 1..then I want to add a new course and so I press the `add-course` button again, and now the id should say `myOption2` and so on..is like creating a `LIKE` button and the number increase every time you press that button

Comment: So you want it to append to an existing list the results it just hot and continue the numbering? You are redecorating your counter each time though starting it at 0. Move that declaration out of the code that runs each time the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try this. I have added a class to the tr so that we can get the already existing tr count and add 1 to it for the next course.

> ```
> var myOption = $('.trRow').length + 1;
>
> for (var i = 0; i < response.course.length; i++) {
>   console.log(response.course.length);
>   $('#table-2 > tbody:last-child')
>       .append('<tr class="trRow" id="optionid' + (myOption++) + '">' +
>           '<td>' + (myOption++) + '</td> ' +
>           '<td>' + response.course[i].strm + '</td> ' +
>           '<td>' + response.course[i].subject + '</td> ' +
>           '<td>' + response.course[i].coursenumber + '</td>  ' +
>           '<td>' + response.course[i].credits + '</td> ' +
>           '<td><a href="#">Delete</a></td> ' +
>           '</tr>');    
>
> }
> ```

2. You can also declare the count variable globally and use it instead of reinitializing its value to 0 in every button click.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The only problem is that every time I add a course it duplicates the last one. For example, if I click add English, it will add English, but then If I want to add Math it will Add English (Again) and math. So, now I have 2 English (same courses) and one math. Then add sociology and it will add English, Math Sociology, English( again), math (again). Any idea why?

Comment: does your response has details related to both (English and Math) courses when you click Math?

Comment: Hi, so far the only thing is the class that you added. Also, the semester...for example, they both are in the fall.

Comment: Also, the form is inside a modal..so when you press the button the same modal opens and has a form asking 4 questions: Semester, subject, course number, and credit.